# What happens to a function called in C from the time being called to the time it returns?

Tags: c, function

Whenever I read about program execution in C, it speaks very less about the function execution. I am still trying to find out what happens to a function when the program starts executing it from the time it is been called from another function to the time it returns? How do the function arguments get stored in memory?

Comment: Implementation/hardware dependant.  Typically, parameters are passed in registers and/or pushed onto a hardware stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's unspecified; it's up to the implementation. As pointed out by Keith Thompson, it doesn't even have to tell you how it works. :)

Some implementations will put all the arguments on the stack, some will use registers, and many use a mix (the first *n* arguments passed in registers, any more and they go on the stack).

But the function itself is just code, it's read-only and nothing much "happens" to it during execution.

Comment: Isn't there a call convention in C ? I though the arguments are always pushed on the stack, which let the possibility to use shared libraries compiled with different compilers.

Comment: @Geoffroy: There is no calling convention associated with the language.

Comment: @Geoffroy Sure, there are several calling conventions and you need to match them to maintain binary compatibility. But the standard doesn't specify them, they're platform and/or compiler dependant.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's unspecified, not implementation defined. The distinction is that the implementation needn't document it.

Comment: @Geoffroy - the shared libs are hardware dependant.  An ARM library will not run on Intel!

Comment: "it doesn't even have to tell you how it works" - which basically is because dlls are outside the scope of the language standard, and if you have no dlls or other calls outside the program, then calling convention is a private matter. Any implementation that wants to support dlls compiled by a different compiler, needs to document a calling convention. Normally you'd use an ABI published by the manufacturer of the CPU, but not always. Calls within the program don't necessarily use the public calling convention: it being unspecified frees the compiler to do what it likes to optimize each call.

Comment: ... for example inlining is a pretty flagrant breach of the public calling convention :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no one correct answer to this question, it depends heavily upon how the compiler writer determines is the best model to do this. There are various bits in the standard that describes this process but most of it is implementation defined. Also, the process is dependent on the architecture of the system, the OS you're aiming for, the level of optimisation and so forth.

Take the following code:-

```
int DoProduct (int a, int b, int c)
{
  return a * b * c;
}

int result = DoProduct (4, 5, 6);
```

The MSVC2005 compiler, using standard debug build options created this for the last line of the above code:-

```
push        6    
push        5    
push        4    
call        DoProduct (411186h) 
add         esp,0Ch 
mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax
```

Here, the arguments are pushed onto the stack, starting with the last argument, then the penultimate argument and so on until the the first argument is pushed onto the stack. The function is called, then the arguments are removed from the stack (the `add esp,0ch`) and then the return value is saved - the result is stored in the eax register.

Here's the code for the function:-

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp 
sub         esp,0C0h 
push        ebx  
push        esi  
push        edi  
lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h] 
mov         ecx,30h 
mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
mov         eax,dword ptr [a] 
imul        eax,dword ptr [b] 
imul        eax,dword ptr [c] 
pop         edi  
pop         esi  
pop         ebx  
mov         esp,ebp 
pop         ebp  
ret
```

The first thing the function does is to create a local stack frame. This involves creating a space on the stack to store local and temporary variables in. In this case, 192 (0xc0) bytes are reserved (the first three instructions). The reason it's so many is to allow the edit-and-continue feature some space to put new variables into.

The next three instructions save the reserved registers as defined by the MS compiler. Then the stack frame space just created is initialised to contain a special debug signature, in this case 0xCC. This means `unitialised memory` and if you ever see a value consisting of just 0xCC's in debug mode then you've forgotten to initialise the value (unless 0xCC was the value).

Once all that housekeeping has been done, the next three instructions implement the body of the function, the two multiplies. After that, the reserved registers are restored and then the stack frame destroyed and finally the function ends with a `ret`. Fortunately, the `imul` puts the result of the multiplication into the `eax` register so there's no special code to get the result into the right register.

Now, you've probably been thinking that there's a lot there that isn't really necessary. And you're right, but debug is about getting the code right and a lot of the above helps to achieve that. In release, there's a lot that can be got rid of. There's no need for a stack frame, no need, therefore, to initialise it. There's no need to save the reserved registers as they aren't modified. In fact, the compiler creates this:-

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4] 
imul        eax,dword ptr [esp+8] 
imul        eax,dword ptr [esp+0Ch] 
ret
```

which, if I'd let the compiler do it, would have been in-lined into the caller.

There's a lot more stuff that can happen: values passed in registers and so on. Also, I've not got into how floating point values and structures / classes as passed to and from functions. And there's more that I've probably left out.